# Flask is installed for Python 2.7 and not for Python 3

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I installed Flask following the steps given in [this webpage](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/installation/), so first I set the enviroment for Python 3 by following command code:

```
pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~/Documents/sva/projekten$  python3 -m venv venv
pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~/Documents/sva/projekten$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv) pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~/Documents/sva/projekten$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

which so far sounds good, then I tried to install Flask and this is what happens:

```
(venv) pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~/Documents/sva/projekten$ sudo pip install flask
[sudo] password for pooja: 
The directory '/home/pooja/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/pooja/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting flask
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e7/08578774ed4536d3242b14dacb4696386634607af824ea997202cd0edb4b/Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 836kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask) (1.0)
Installing collected packages: flask
Successfully installed flask-1.0.2
(venv) pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~/Documents/sva/projekten$ flask --version
Flask 1.0.2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
(venv) pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~/Documents/sva/projekten$
```

Does anybody have any ideas, how can I install Flask for Python 3 and not for Python 2.7?

Comment: Why did you use `sudo pip`? That's switching to a different user (`root`), and **out of the virtualenv**.

Comment: You appear to have included a link to a webpage at some point, but the link was lost early on. What page did you mean to link to? For now I assume you were linking to the [Flask installation documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/stable/installation/), as the virtualenv commands match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created and activated a virtualenv, and **then ignored it**, because you used `sudo`:

```
$ sudo pip install flask
```

Activating a virtualenv simply sets the `PATH` variable to put the commands in the `bin` directory first when running `pip`, `python`, etc.

But when you use `sudo`, you create a new sub-shell running under the `root` user, and you then effectively tell the OS to *not use the current shell configuration*. And the `pip` command found *when executing as the `root` user* is not the same command as the one set up for your virtualenv.

Next, you would not want to install packages as root into your virtualenv anyway. Install them as the current user instead.

Simply drop the `sudo`:

```
$ pip install flask
```

or even directly reference the `bin/pip` command:

```
$ bin/pip install flask
```

The whole point of a virtualenv is to give you an isolated Python environment that is your own, where you can add and remove packages as you need to, without needing root access.

Comment: thanks. Hoever, there is error message while installing flask'  
  Complete output from command /home/pooja/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-t0wz3cos/itsdangerous/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpq3rodakhpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help
 
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
'Any idea?

Comment: See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-pip-setuptools-and-wheel-are-up-to-date; the command `pip install -U pip setuptools wheel` should set you up with the most up-to-date toolchain. Run that in the virtualenv.